# How to enable fulltext search on PII data that needs to be encrypted

Tags: search, encryption, database-design, full-text-search

We're developing a service that imports HR data (name, email, role, pay, management hierarchy, and so on) from HR tools such as Workday and keeps it in our system. This system is the foundation for a number of downstream applications. We need to allow fulltext search on this data so that the admin can find persons quickly.

Is it even possible to do so? Isn't it going to be really slow if there's a system that handles encryption at rest and supports fulltext search on that data? What does the solution for this usecase look like in other companies that perform comparable things?

Comment: What is PII data?

Comment: [Personally Identifiable Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data). Things like email, phone, ssn, etc.

Comment: How accurate the search hits should be (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)? Do you need "best ranked results" or "some result" or "all the matching documents? or How fast should the query be: sub-second or a second / minute / hour / day? What is the expected workload regarding read and write? I guess consistency is must have, how fast do you need writes to be available for read? Do you need deep traversal kind of queries? Do you need textual search, and / or multiple criteria look up with exact match, sorting, and possibly facets?

Comment: Results need to be accurate, and would expect sorting by rank - similar to fuzzy 
or semantic search to some degree. We would also expect the results to be quick. sub second with about a million records may be acceptable. faceting and sorting are also functionality that will be desirable.

Comment: Very interesting question. I would try to provide an answer if there was bounty.